# which python package can replace linphone in Android and JAVA

Tags: python, linphone

I find a demo using linphone to call someone in a java project,but now I want to find a package can sovle the same problem like the linphone.I don't know what can help me.For help

Comment: Sorry,I want to find a python package

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dev in python you can used the linphone sdk python:

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/linphone
>   Docs:
>   https://pythonhosted.org/linphone/